# how can i call function when clicked angular 6 mat-table pagination buttons for update table value

Tags: angular, pagination

In `angular 6` I want to display in `mat-table` the first page after initializing it with default values `startIndex` and `endIndex`.

But after I click on the pagination buttons, the table values are not updated, but `pageValues` changed.

`getRangeLabel` function returns the correct value but

```
<div>Start Index: {{startIndex}} </div>
<div>End Index: {{endIndex}} </div>
```

not updated.

Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manager',
  templateUrl: './manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manager.component.scss'],
  providers: [{ provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: ManagerComponent }]
})
export class ManagerComponent extends MatPaginatorIntl implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  displayedColumns = [];

  dataSource;
  display$ = false;
  pageSize = 25;
  resultsLength;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];
  startIndex = 0;
  endIndex = 25;

  constructor(private http: DataService) { super() }

  getDrid(start: number, stop: number) {
    this.http.getUsers(start, stop)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data.success) {
            this.resultsLength = data.rowcount;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.result.rows);
            for (let index = 1; index < data.result.metaData.length; index++) {
              this.displayedColumns.push(data.result.metaData[index].name);
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.display$ = true;
            }, 0);
          }
        });
  };

  getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
    if (length == 0 || pageSize == 0) {
      return `0 of ${length}`;
    }
    length = Math.max(length, 0);
    this.startIndex = page * pageSize;
    this.endIndex = this.startIndex < length ? Math.min(this.startIndex + pageSize, length) : this.startIndex + pageSize;

    return this.startIndex + ' - ' + this.endIndex + ' of ' + length;
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getDrid(this.startIndex, this.endIndex);
  }
}
```

And here is a screenshot

[[image]]

Comment: How are you sending the `StartIndex` and `EndIndex` to the server to get a new data? I only see you initialized it once which is `0` and `25` on `ngAfterViewInit` when you made an http call with those values.

Comment: Hey @penleychan. thanks for answer. I'm new to the angular. service works correctly with this values. but I can not send the new request again with new startIndex and endIndex values. help me if u can.